# sql query required grouping column in single row

Tags: sql

I have following table structure

```
TicketID    Status  Duration
-----------------------------
1234           8        2
1233           8       10
1232           4        5
1231           8       12
1230           4       50
```

- status 8 means Closed
- status 4 means Open

It is required to have output in following way. Please do the need ful. If possible I wanted it in a single sql query.

Please help me to produce output in following way.

```
Row     Closed (sum)    Open(Sum)
---------------------------------
   1       24              55
```

Comment: _"Please do the need ful"_ huh? Have _you_ tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 1 as row, 
       sum(case when status = 8 then 1 else 0 end) as closed,
       sum(case when status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as open
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
1 as Row,
sum(case when Status=8 then 1 else 0 end  ) as Closed_Sum,
sum(case when Status=4 then 1 else 0 end  ) as Open_Sum
  from 
Mytable
```

Comment: Thank you,It has been working.